# Trying to build a little script for orphaned words:

Tags: javascript

I wanted to make a really simple script to deal with some orphaned words in some of my headlines. I thought I did a pretty neat job, but then the first words get cut off. Any help understanding why?

```
var buddyUpOrphans = function(element, howMany) {
    $(element).each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var thisText = $this.text().split(' ');
        var wordLength = thisText.length;
        thisText.splice( (wordLength - howMany), 0, '<nobr>');
        thisText.shift('</nobr>');
        thisText = thisText.join(' ');
        $this.html(thisText);
    });
};
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/waXZYJ?editors=101)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    buddyUpOrphans('p', 2);
    buddyUpOrphans('.test1', 4);
});
```

Comment: Check this code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjRzRj

Comment: I commented this line `thisText.shift('</nobr>');` , why do you need javascrip\t array shift?

Comment: Did you mean to use [`Array.prototype.unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)?

Comment: It would have thought so, but that doesn't make much since either, because then the closing tag `</nobr>` would be before the opening tag `<nobr>`. `.push` makes more sense here.

Comment: RE: shift, I was looking at something that was changing the beginning of the sentence, and since I don't do a lot of work with strings, I just assumed it was doing something else.

Comment: Where does the `</nobr>` come in then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.shift` method *removes the first element of the array* (and doesn't take any arguments), whereas is seems like you want to add something to the end of the array. You can use the `.push` method for this.

Since you are adding the `<nobr>` and `</nobr>` as elements to the array, and then doing `.join(" ")`, this does have the unintended consequence of putting spaces around them.

I would recommend concatenating the `<nobr>` and `</nobr>` at the end of some elements of the array rather than insering them into the array.

```js
var buddyUpOrphans = function(element, howMany) {
 $(element).each( function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var thisText = $this.text().split(' ');
  var wordLength = thisText.length;
  thisText[wordLength - howMany - 1] += "<nobr>";
  thisText[wordLength - 1] += '</nobr>';
  thisText = thisText.join(' ');
  $this.html(thisText);
 });
};


$(document).ready( function() {
 buddyUpOrphans('p', 2);
 buddyUpOrphans('.test1', 4);
});
```

```css
body { 
 color: red;
}
 
nobr {
 color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='test1'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet voluptates aperiam cumque, qui error, aliquam velit hic ad sapiente accusamus totam id similique repudiandae doloribus, optio consequatur, voluptatum maiores quod?</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa laudantium rem ut id delectus at eaque inventore rerum, dolorem nisi alias modi asperiores recusandae nulla, iure. Facilis consequatur, impedit ipsa.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using [`arr.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift);

It removes the first element of the array and returns that array.
To add elements, use [`arr.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push);